# How to automate the format of a text file to have the lenght of the longest string in the list be the the number of characters.for that variable

Tags: python, string

I know the command to use a certain length, s and it gets me what i want.  However i would like to automate it, so that the number of characters will vary from run to run

I have a list:

```
x1 = ['IMG_0187_1.JPG', 'IMG_0668.JPG', 'IMG_1177.JPG']
```

I find the my max length of the strings

```
max_len = -1
for ele in x1: 
    if len(ele) > max_len: 
        max_len = int(len(ele))
```

now i want to use that max length in this command:

```
with open(sizefile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('{:14}'.format(x[1])) -> instead i want this f.write('{:max_len}'.format(x[1]))
```

'{:14}'.format(x[1]) - this gives me what i want, but I want to script it because the max length is not always going to be 14 in other runs.

I get this error:  ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Is it possible to automate this command somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The format itself is a string that you can format with placeholders :

```
>>> max_len=5
>>> '{:%s}'%(max_len)
'{:5}'
```

So the following code should work in your case :

```
s='{:%s}'%(max_len)
f.write(s.format(x[1]))
```